# Is it possible to load erb using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am new to Javascript and Ruby so this question may sound silly.

The fundamental problem I try to address is:

In the main erb file, there is the following line.

```
...
<div>
...
<%= erb :page1, :locals => { :vt => var1 } %>
</div>
```

The issue of "page1.erb" is that it will for some reason do a refresh, which causes the main page to also get refreshed.

So how to restrict the scope of refreshing in this case?

I am thinking to put the loading of erb within ajax call. But I haven't found how to do that yet (maybe not possible?). The closest one I found is "$.getScript", but this is to load js file not erb. Not sure if it can work and even so how to pass ":locals".

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Just use load() - https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @JayBlanchard, Thank you. How to transmit :locals? Is it just to encode in URL? If so, "page1.erb" cannot use because it has no "params[vt]" within it.

Comment: This library of mine may interest you: http://phrogz.net/JS/AJAXFetch/ It makes it easy to reload partials via jQuery. (And yes, you have to supply enough data in the query string or form variables to be able to construct the partial again.)

Comment: "load()" does not work, still refresh the whole page. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Erb templates run on the server side and are parsed by ruby.

You can create a partial such as _myfile.js.erb and then you can return via ajax. Finally however js is returned to the browser.

This is an example of a js.erb file

```
$('#cart').hide('blind',1000);
$('#cart').html("<%=j render @cart %>");
```